# How to extend PageLinkHandler to accept an anchor on a Page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to extend Wagtail's PageLinkHandler to combine an internal `PageChooser` link with an `AnchorLink`, so the template output is `<a href="/mypage#myanchor"`.

```
class AnchorPageLinkHandler(PageLinkHandler):
    identifier = 'page_anchor'

    @staticmethod
    def get_model():
        return Page

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, attrs):
        return super().get_instance(attrs).specific

    @classmethod
    def expand_db_attributes(cls, attrs):
        try:
            page = cls.get_instance(attrs)
            hash_id = attrs["hash_id"]
            return '<a href="{}#{}">'.format(escape(
                page.localized.specific.url), hash_id)
        except Page.DoesNotExist:
            return "<a>"


@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_link_handler(features):
    features.register_link_type(AnchorPageLinkHandler)
```

I have got this far, but have 2 problems: i) `page_anchor` does not show up in the link editor widget, how do I enable this? ii) how do I add the `hash_id` text input to the widget when I do enable it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?
I’m also looking to extend wagtail to enable anchors links on other pages

Answer (score 0):

I have created package [Wagtailset](https://github.com/dest81/wagtailset#wagtail_draftail_anchored_internal_links) that might do what you are looking for:

1. It extends link widget with extra option to add/edit anchor in the rich text editor (see screenshot). This option is only available for internal links.
   [image]
2. It renders link with anchor almost in the same way as you described in question: `<a href="/page3/#header-1">bla</a>`

P.S. Let me know if you have any idea(s) how it can be improved.